# Inequality involving a product over the primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, products

Is there someone who is able to prove the following statement?

$$\prod_{m=1}^n \dfrac{p_m-1}{p_m} \leq \dfrac{1}{\ln(n)}$$ for all integers $n >1$ where $p_m$ is the $m$-th prime number.

Comment: Not sure if this will help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html.

Comment: Could you provide some context? Why do you think that this inequality holds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I've left my previous flawed approach. It is interesting that my upvoters and I hadn't noticed the highlighted mistake. And also that there exists a very straightforward proof: $$\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{p_m}{p_m-1}-\ln n>\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{m}-\ln n>\gamma>0. $$

---

If you wish to avoid Mertens but not Rosser, note that your inequality is weaker than $$\begin{align}\prod_{m=1}^n\frac{p_m-1}{p_m}&\le\frac{n}{p_n} \\ (p_n-1)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{p_m-1}{p_m}&\le n \\ p_n-1&\le n\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{p_m}{p_m-1}, \end{align}$$which holds for $n=2$ and for larger $n$ follows from  $$\begin{align} \color\red{\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p_n-1}}\require{enclose}  \enclose{updiagonalstrike,downdiagonalstrike}{\frac{p_n}{p_n-1}} &<\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{p_n}{p_n-1}    \\ \color\red{p_n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)&>\enclose{updiagonalstrike,downdiagonalstrike}1\color\red{p_{n+1}-1} \\ \color\red{p_{n+1}-p_{n}} &\color\red{<}\color\red{\frac{p_n}{n}+1} \longrightarrow \text{stronger than Cramer's conjecture}\end{align}$$In fact, *too* stronger. It fails **infinitely often**, as a consequence of Westzynthius's result (kindly reminded by wythagoras in the comments): $$\lim\sup\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log p_n}=\infty.$$

Comment: +1. Personally I think this answer is much better because in the other answer we have the $\sim$ sign which is not a proof.

Comment: @wythagoras Maybe it wasn't. Should have I slept longer in these days or did we all miss the mistake I made? See my edit.

Comment: @Vicenzo Oliva, indeed, I missed that. But I only looked whether the general idea is correct. (By the way, I've seen worse – three votes within the first 30 seconds of posting while the post contained a mistake)

Comment: @whythagoras My God, lol. Something tells me it was from someone with a very high rep. Anyway, thank you, cheers.

Comment: Also, E. Westzynthius proved in 1931 that the red statement fails infinitely often by showing that $$\lim \sup \frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log p_n} = \infty$$ Oh, and regarding that post, it was just an arithmetical error, but a quite obvious one.  And the author didn't have very high rep. In fact, he currently has 8,984 rep. (I was the author, in other words)

Comment: @whythagoras Uh, yeah, had forgotten about that result. Hah, that's unexpected! :D I guess we all miss something, sometimes.

Comment: @wythagoras I edited to include Westzynthius's result, crediting you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

We have $$\prod_{i\leq n}\frac{p_{i}-1}{p_{i}}=\prod_{i\leq n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}\right)=\frac{1}{\log\left(p_{n}\right)e^{\gamma}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\log^{2}\left(p_{n}\right)}\right)
 $$ by the [Mertens theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html). Now note that, by [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem) $$\frac{1}{\log\left(p_{n}\right)e^{\gamma}}<\frac{1}{\log\left(p_{n}\right)}<\frac{1}{\log\left(n\log\left(n\right)\right)}=\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)+\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}\leq\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}.
 $$

Comment: thanks a lot!   As I can see we do not need  Rosser's theorem. It is enough to note that we have: $n<p_n$.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) I use it only because $p_{n}\sim n\log\left(n\right)$ hence I thought to Rosser's theorem.